# Use non-static variable with chrome.storage.local.set / get

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, google-chrome-app

Is it possible to use a non static variable with chrome.storage.local.get. Right now, I can not recover anything.

here's what I do:

```
myVar = 'test'; 
var obj = {}; 
obj[myVar] = Output; 
storage.set(obj);
```

and to recover, I do:

```
var key = example + 'js'; 
storage.get(key, function (result) {
console.log (result.key)
});
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't understand your problem here.

Comment: I save a variable that I want to recover any time. But the name of my variable carries the project name in which the user work. As can be several projects, I want to retrieve information related to the project. And I do not know in advance the project name that the user will give his project. So when I get done, I get the name of the project via a button and that's how I chrome.storage.local call to retrieve the information.

ex: there is a projected A, B, C. I want to be filled, when click the B, retrieve information that I had saved earlier. But I can not.

Is that clearer?

Comment: No, not much clearer. Do you want to retrieve the list of keys / all of the data in the storage not knowing the key?

Comment: This is exactly the idea. Recover the key that I do not know the name. If I could retrieve them, would be great. Is this possible?

Thank you very much in advance! I'm sorry, my English is not so good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `null` as the query to retrieve the whole storage:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(data) {
  // data contains everything in storage
});
```

Comment: and to retrieve the values I console.log (data), right?

Comment: Define "retrieve". You can use them as you wish.

Comment: See the data storage... But I think I understood the idea :) Thanks so much for all

Comment: For more practical advice: if you're going to store several keys with names you don't know, store along an object containing all those keys. It will be easier.

Comment: Or use a query-able storage like web sql or indexed db. Will have much better performance if you are storing a lot of pairs (say over 1000)